# How do I make a string only X char and specific?

Tags: c#

I don't know if you got me what I'm trying to explain... (English is not my main language).

Ok here, I got this string `590CBC145FA` and this one `F6EC5CA9A` and the only part that I want, no matter how long is the string, is the last eight char like this: `CBC145FA` `6EC5CA9A`. The `590` and `F` are obsolete to me, like: `!S!ZV)+D_?CEFZEZAF` = `CEFZ!Z#F`.

I tried to use `serial.Substring(3);` only work for the first one: `590CBC145FA` = `CBC145FA`

If I try to use `serial.Substring(1);` it work for `F6EC5CA9A` = `6EC5CA9A`

But what happen if I get a string very long and I don't know how much the obsolete part is... I can't use `serial.Substring(X);` because I don't, like I said, how long is the obsolete part.

I only want to get the eight last char of any serial no matter how long is.

Comment: Maybe `EndsWith`? Try searching the `String` documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

*You want to get the eight last char of any serial no matter how long is.*

```
string test = "F6EC5CA9A";
string result = test;
if (test.Length >= 8)
    result = test.Substring(test.Length-8);
```

You just need to discover the index of the 8th character before the end of the string. And this could be easily calculated using the Length property of every string.

Of course you need to be sure that your string is at least 8 characters. You don't say what do you want in case this length is less than 8, so I assume that you want the original input back